# Jasper Report list comes empty when using an XML source

Tags: xml, jasper-reports

I'm currently trying to use a list component inside JasperReports for the first time, and I'm finding difficulties.

Inside JR Studio, I configured the list correctly and managed to display it in the preview; however, when using the report in Java I feed it the `JRXmlDataSource` correctly (since it displays data inside the report), but it doesn't reach the list component, which displays 0 rows.

What I tried and didn't work:

- Passing the `XML_DATA_DOCUMENT` parameter (it was how it worked inside JR Studio, no such luck outside of it), or the `XML_INPUT_STREAM` one, or any number of the `XML_` default parameters
- Storing the `JRXmlDataSource` in a parameter and passing it to the list as `REPORT_DATA_SOURCE`
- Passing the aforementioned `JRXmlDataSource`-in-a-parameter as `<dataSourceExpression>`
- Changing the evaluation time of the text fields inside the list to `Auto`, or checking the `Print when Overflow` box

What did work:

- Feeding the list an empty data source (so I know it can actually display something where I want it to)

I'm swamped here; so far none of the searches I made had turned up something that worked for me. Is there something I'm missing?

Here is the `.jrxml` file (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-02-21T12:03:07 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="InterventoDipendente" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="96a3ac3a-7d55-40dc-bf6d-11204521d521">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DataAdapter.xml"/>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="0852c8da-7fc3-4f80-b57b-43807b503678">
        <parameter name="dipId" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <queryString language="xPath">
            <![CDATA[/list/intervento]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="voceCodice_1" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[voce/descrizione]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="durata_1" class="java.lang.Double">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[durata]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="dataIntervento_1" class="java.util.Date">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dataIntervento]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="dipendenteId_1" class="java.lang.Long">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dipendente/id]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <sortField name="dataIntervento_1"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="XML_DATA_SOURCE" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString language="XPath">
        <![CDATA[/list/intervento]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="dataIntervento" class="java.util.Date">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dataIntervento]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="dipendenteId" class="java.lang.Long">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dipendente/id]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="dipendenteNome" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dipendenteNome]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="durata" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[durata]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="voceC" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[voce/codice]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <sortField name="dipendenteId"/>
    <variable name="durata1" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Dipendente" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{durata}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="ass" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Dipendente" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{voceC}.equals("Ass_sist") ? $F{durata} : 0.0)]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Dipendente" isStartNewPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{dipendenteId}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="120">
                <textField pattern="0.#">
                    <reportElement x="100" y="60" width="80" height="30" uuid="48f3f8ea-b083-47cf-9a9f-323ad86829a4"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{durata1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="ca3d0a18-c276-4f1b-8e00-c13a2fea64f7"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dipendenteNome}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement key="" positionType="Float" x="180" y="30" width="372" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="afdd4606-9306-4c0d-8a94-0ce962b91b8a">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value="List1"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="f805abf9-255f-46d7-b0ca-c9e971c63e78">
                            <datasetParameter name="dipId">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{dipendenteId}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="XML_DATE_PATTERN">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="XML_DATA_DOCUMENT">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_DATA_DOCUMENT}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="XML_INPUT_STREAM">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_INPUT_STREAM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{XML_DATA_SOURCE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:listContents height="30" width="372">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="124" height="30" uuid="3e35abd0-d7b2-450d-99af-8ff22943556b"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{voceCodice_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="0.#">
                                <reportElement x="124" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="5c162489-ef8c-4fdc-a586-158952d4fc8b"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{durata_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="dd-MM-yy">
                                <reportElement x="248" y="0" width="124" height="30" uuid="16e276ff-7506-4e13-bf64-8c64d461dc63"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dataIntervento_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Auto">
                                <reportElement x="190" y="0" width="58" height="30" uuid="3e110827-40e4-4c51-96f6-d47a685f79e8"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["s"]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:listContents>
                    </jr:list>
                </componentElement>
                <textField pattern="MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4337a281-fbaf-49cf-af9a-0e14201d5d5b"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dataIntervento}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="7bd7832d-665d-4a8e-af00-004ab5586803"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{coan.intervento.voce.list}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="5edf1da6-5172-46aa-809a-ed287cf9411b"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{coan.intervento.durataIntervento.list}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="430" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="cff409d1-5834-4597-81ee-85236a29d773"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{coan.intervento.dataIntervento.list}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="100" height="30" uuid="7fbbf46d-c93e-478a-9880-53bb4caae1d5"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Totale Ore ="]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="100" height="30" uuid="b52dfdc1-22a2-4d51-b4ba-dbaf13eaeb14"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Di cui lavorate ="]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="250" height="30" uuid="5dc33e9c-3e91-42c8-8639-e2b3b0c8f60e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{coan.repFattIntDip.titolo.list}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

A sample XML file for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<list>
    <intervento>
        <id>64153</id>
        <dataIntervento>2017-02-16T00:00:00+01:00</dataIntervento>
        <durata>2.0</durata>
        <dipendente>
            <id>82</id>
            <lastUpdate>2012-06-18T15:09:41.206+02:00</lastUpdate>
            <utenteLog_id>9185</utenteLog_id>
            <nome>EMANUELE</nome>
            <cognome>RAGNI</cognome>
            <titolo>PROGRAMMATORE</titolo>
        </dipendente>
        <commessa>
            <autocompleteView>AMMORTAMENTI - AMMORTAMENTI</autocompleteView>
            <codice>AMMORTAMENTI</codice>
            <descrizione>AMMORTAMENTI</descrizione>
            <id>49377</id>
            <lastUpdate>2016-04-14T13:04:22.871+02:00</lastUpdate>
            <utenteLog_id>9185</utenteLog_id>
            <chiusa>false</chiusa>
            <codiceDestinazione>AMM AMMORTAMENTI E SVALUTAZIONI</codiceDestinazione>
            <commessaTipo>
                <autocompleteView>MCI - MATERIALI E COSTI INDIVISIBILI</autocompleteView>
                <codice>MCI</codice>
                <descrizione>MATERIALI E COSTI INDIVISIBILI</descrizione>
                <id>70</id>
            </commessaTipo>
            <destinazione>
                <autocompleteView>AMM - AMMORTAMENTI E SVALUTAZIONI</autocompleteView>
                <codice>AMM</codice>
                <descrizione>AMMORTAMENTI E SVALUTAZIONI</descrizione>
                <id>49422</id>
                <lastUpdate>2016-04-14T13:03:05.182+02:00</lastUpdate>
                <utenteLog_id>9185</utenteLog_id>
                <tipo>1</tipo>
            </destinazione>
        </commessa>
        <voce>
            <autocompleteView>Ass_sist - assistenza tecnica e sistemisticaaas</autocompleteView>
            <codice>Ass_sist</codice>
            <descrizione>assistenza tecnica e sistemisticaaas</descrizione>
            <id>47399</id>
            <lastUpdate>2017-02-06T12:29:58.823+01:00</lastUpdate>
            <utenteLog_id>3</utenteLog_id>
            <costi>false</costi>
            <dipendenti>false</dipendenti>
            <ricavi>true</ricavi>
        </voce>
        <dipendenteNome>EMANUELE  RAGNI</dipendenteNome>
        <commessaCodice>AMMORTAMENTI - AMMORTAMENTI</commessaCodice>
        <voceCodice>Ass_sist - assistenza tecnica e sistemisticaaas</voceCodice>
    </intervento>
    <intervento>
        <id>64131</id>
        <dataIntervento>2017-02-14T00:00:00+01:00</dataIntervento>
        <durata>2.0</durata>
        <dipendente>
            <id>81</id>
            <nome>MATTEO</nome>
            <cognome>BERELLINI</cognome>
            <titolo>SOCIO</titolo>
        </dipendente>
        <commessa>
            <autocompleteView>AMM - AMMINISTRAZIONE</autocompleteView>
            <codice>AMM</codice>
            <descrizione>AMMINISTRAZIONE</descrizione>
            <id>68</id>
            <lastUpdate>2017-02-14T10:39:29.535+01:00</lastUpdate>
            <utenteLog_id>9520</utenteLog_id>
            <chiusa>false</chiusa>
            <cliente>
                <autocompleteView>CRNCST74M01I653T-972712 - TABACCHERIA DI CERIONI CRISTIANO </autocompleteView>
                <codice>CRNCST74M01I653T-972712</codice>
                <descrizione>CRNCST74M01I653T-972712</descrizione>
                <id>46758</id>
                <anagrafica>TABACCHERIA DI CERIONI CRISTIANO </anagrafica>
                <codiceAnagraficaCategoria></codiceAnagraficaCategoria>
                <codiceAnagraficaCategoria2></codiceAnagraficaCategoria2>
                <codiceAnagraficaCategoria3></codiceAnagraficaCategoria3>
                <codiceBanca></codiceBanca>
                <codiceBancaTerzi></codiceBancaTerzi>
                <codiceCodiceIva></codiceCodiceIva>
                <codiceCodiceRivalsa></codiceCodiceRivalsa>
                <codiceDestinatarioPrivati>0000000</codiceDestinatarioPrivati>
                <codiceFiscale>CRNCST74M01I653T</codiceFiscale>
                <codiceLingua></codiceLingua>
                <codiceModTras></codiceModTras>
                <codicePagamento></codicePagamento>
                <codiceValuta></codiceValuta>
                <codiceVettore></codiceVettore>
                <disabledCreaProfilo>false</disabledCreaProfilo>
                <fax></fax>
                <flagAnagraficaFatturazionePred>false</flagAnagraficaFatturazionePred>
                <flagAnagraficaSpedizionePred>false</flagAnagraficaSpedizionePred>
                <flagCliente>true</flagCliente>
                <flagFornitore>true</flagFornitore>
                <flagIvaPerCassa>false</flagIvaPerCassa>
                <flagProfiloCreato>true</flagProfiloCreato>
                <indirizzo>P.ZZA DELLA LIBERTà,3 </indirizzo>
                <mysondId>972712</mysondId>
                <partitaIva>02370740421</partitaIva>
                <partitaIvaInternazionale>IT</partitaIvaInternazionale>
                <personaFisica>false</personaFisica>
                <sito></sito>
                <stato>1</stato>
                <telefono1></telefono1>
            </cliente>
            <codiceCliente>CRNCST74M01I653T-972712 TABACCHERIA DI CERIONI CRISTIANO </codiceCliente>
            <codiceDestinazione>AM AMMINISTRAZIONE</codiceDestinazione>
            <commessaTipo>
                <autocompleteView>AM - AMMINISTRAZIONE</autocompleteView>
                <codice>AM</codice>
                <descrizione>AMMINISTRAZIONE</descrizione>
                <id>71</id>
            </commessaTipo>
            <descrizioneCliente>null null</descrizioneCliente>
            <destinazione>
                <autocompleteView>AM - AMMINISTRAZIONE</autocompleteView>
                <codice>AM</codice>
                <descrizione>AMMINISTRAZIONE</descrizione>
                <id>74</id>
                <lastUpdate>2015-11-19T12:58:50.607+01:00</lastUpdate>
                <utenteLog_id>9185</utenteLog_id>
                <tipo>3</tipo>
            </destinazione>
        </commessa>
        <voce>
            <autocompleteView>Ass_sist - assistenza tecnica e sistemisticaaas</autocompleteView>
            <codice>Ass_sist</codice>
            <descrizione>assistenza tecnica e sistemisticaaas</descrizione>
            <id>47399</id>
            <lastUpdate>2017-02-06T12:29:58.823+01:00</lastUpdate>
            <utenteLog_id>3</utenteLog_id>
            <costi>false</costi>
            <dipendenti>false</dipendenti>
            <ricavi>true</ricavi>
        </voce>
        <dipendenteNome>MATTEO  BERELLINI</dipendenteNome>
        <commessaCodice>AMM - AMMINISTRAZIONE</commessaCodice>
        <voceCodice>Ass_sist - assistenza tecnica e sistemisticaaas</voceCodice>
    </intervento>
</list>
```

And the adapter for it, if there's need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xmlDataAdapter class="net.sf.jasperreports.data.xml.XmlDataAdapterImpl"><name>InterventiDipendente</name><dataFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="repositoryDataLocation"><location>C:\Users\rbroccoletti\Desktop\interventi.xml</location></dataFile><useConnection>true</useConnection><namespaceAware>false</namespaceAware><datePattern>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss</datePattern><selectExpression>/</selectExpression><locale xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:java="http://java.sun.com" xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">en_US</locale><timeZone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:java="http://java.sun.com" xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">Europe/Berlin</timeZone></xmlDataAdapter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out what I was missing -- calling `.dataSource(query)` on the `JRXmlDataSource` I was passing. The `REPORT_DATA_SOURCE` was not usable in this manner since it had become an unusable `SortedDataSource`, and I forgot this extra step when bringing it from a custom parameter.